# Where to put a class on the f.select in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to apply a class to a select form element that is built with Ruby.

Here is the f.select:

```
<%= f.select :within, ["5km", "50km", "100km", "250km", "500km", "1000km"], { :include_blank => 'Anywhere', :selected => (params[:listing][:within] unless params[:listing].nil? || !params[:listing].has_key?(:within)) } %>
```

Where does the class go? My class is:

```
:class => 'input-medium'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See **[the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select)**, specifically the `html_options` argument.

Add yet another argument onto the end of what you've posted in your question with:

```
{ class: "input-medium" }
```

Altogether that's

```
<%= f.select :within, ["5km", "50km", "100km", "250km", "500km", "1000km"], { :include_blank => 'Anywhere', :selected => (params[:listing][:within] unless params[:listing].nil? || !params[:listing].has_key?(:within)) }, { class: "input-medium" } %>
```